# Python class members with dynamic names

Tags: python, class, dynamic

I've seen a class in python which does something of this kind:

obj = Class( name = "somename" )
obj.somename = something

Namely the class initialisation created a member called as the argument string.
I cannot manage to reproduce this behaviour. Any ideas?

I managed to do something similar using globals()["name"] = value. But in this case the created object is son of the module not of the "Class" object. And it's callable as module.somename instead of obj.somename.

Comment: You can do `obj.somename = something` on *any* instance of a class (that doesn't define `__slots__`). The question is, you you expect some particular behavior with it, like the attribute being initialized with something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create a dynamically named member by using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         setattr(self, name, 42)
...
>>> f = Foo('bar')
>>> f.bar
42
>>> f.bar = 'hello'
>>> f.bar
'hello'
```

Note however, that just setting any attribute on an instance of a class is possible for any regular class (that doesn't define [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots)):

```
>>> class Qux(object):
...     pass
...
>>> q = Qux()
>>> q.foobar = 'hello'
>>> q.foobar
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a dynamically named fixed value property like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.__dict__[attr] = 'some_value'
```

Or create as many properties as the calling function wants:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, *argv, **kwargs):
        for key,value in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = value
```